# Corrupt UDP Packet java

Tags: java, udp

Sender

```
package core;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import message.JOutMessages;

/**
 * 
 * @author padaboo I.B Aleksandrov jetananas@yandex.ru
 */
public class JUDPSender extends Thread{
    /**
     * run stop flag
     */
    public static boolean isRunning = true;
    /**
     * pool size
     */
    public int poolSize;
    /**
     * out passage
     */
    public JOutMessages message;
    /**
     * client port
     */
    public int clientPort;

    public JUDPSender(int poolSize,int clientPort){
        this.poolSize    = poolSize;
        this.clientPort  = clientPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            ExecutorService executor   =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
            DatagramSocket socket      =  new DatagramSocket();

            DatagramPacket packet;
            byte[] buffer;
            InetAddress inetAddress;
            JUDPSenderHandler handler;

            while(JUDPSender.isRunning){

                for (String key : JOutMessages.getKeySet()) {

                    message     =  (JOutMessages) JOutMessages.get(key);

                    buffer      = message.json.toJSONString().getBytes();

                    //System.out.println(message.json.toJSONString());

                    inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(message.ip);

                    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, inetAddress, this.clientPort);

                    handler = new JUDPSenderHandler(socket,packet);
                    executor.execute(handler);

                } 
            }
        } catch ( SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JUDPSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex){

        }
    }

    class JUDPSenderHandler implements Runnable{

        /**
         * datagram socket
         */
        DatagramSocket socket;
        /**
         * datagram packet
         */
        DatagramPacket packet;

        public JUDPSenderHandler(DatagramSocket socket,DatagramPacket packet) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.packet = packet;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                socket.send(packet);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JUDPSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recivier

```
/*
 * jsock framework https://github.com/nnpa/jsock open source
 * Each line should be prefixed with  * 
 */

package jsock.core;

import conf.JConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import jsock.message.JInMessages;

/**
 * 
 * @author padaboo I.B Aleksandrov jetananas@yandex.ru
 */
public class JUDPRecivier extends Thread{

    /**
     * server port
     */
    private final int port;
    /**
     * pool size
     */
    private final int poolSize;
    /**
     * run stop flag
     */
    public static boolean isRunning = true;

    public JUDPRecivier(int poolSize,int port){
        this.port     = port;
        this.poolSize = poolSize;
    }

    /**
     * Create thread poll 
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port)) {

            ExecutorService executor     = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

            byte[] receiveData           = new byte[JConfig.socket_buffer_size];


            while(JUDPRecivier.isRunning){
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket ( receiveData, receiveData.length );
                serverSocket.receive ( receivePacket );

                executor.execute(
                    new JUDPRecivierHandler(serverSocket,receivePacket)
                );
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JTCPReciver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Listen user sockets 
     * send messages to message list
     * send connection to connection list
     */
    class JUDPRecivierHandler implements Runnable{
        //socket
        DatagramSocket socket;

        DatagramPacket receivePacket;

        public JUDPRecivierHandler(DatagramSocket serverSocket,DatagramPacket receivePacket) {
            this.socket        = serverSocket;
            this.receivePacket = receivePacket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InetAddress inetAdress    = receivePacket.getAddress();
            String ip = inetAdress.getHostAddress();

            byte[] data = new byte[receivePacket.getLength()];

            data  = receivePacket.getData();

            String stringData = new String(data,0, receivePacket.getLength());

            JInMessages inputSocketMessage = new JInMessages(ip,stringData);
            inputSocketMessage.insert();
        }
    }
}
```

Send packet

> {"task":"JGameTask","data":{"isDirectRight":false,"Left":false,"blockMove":false,"fallSpeed":100,"LeftRelease":false,"LClickRelease":false,"DownRelease":false,"Right":false,"SitRelease":false,"camLeftZ":0.08650045,"camLeftY":-4.0163286E-9,"camLeftX":-0.18032658,"speed":1.0,"LClick":false,"camRotationW":-0.22177358,"camRotationX":-2.1658896E-4,"JumpRelease":false,"startLocation":{"x":-67.11953,"y":8.058952,"z":-55.18904},"camRotationY":0.9750977,"camRotationZ":-9.522566E-4,"levelId":"Gilkph036QbP","isRightDirect":false,"isSitRight":false,"Down":false,"camDirectionZ":-0.2704894,"RightRelease":false,"isDirectLeft":false,"camDirectionX":-0.12975043,"camDirectionY":-5.859462E-4,"CtrlRelease":false,"isSit":false,"isSitLeft":false,"Ctrl":false,"Jump":false,"isAnimRun":false,"isLeftDirect":false,"command":1,"rotateAnimation":"direct","isSitRun":false,"runAnimation":"run","gravity":60,"UpRelease":false,"Up":false,"Sit":false,"isStand":false},"user_id":"18","scenario":"send_keys","auth_token":"c0facde0aa585dc4b7e0a6d820bb3df41499141302"}

Receive with error:  at end **2"}**

> {"task":"JGameTask","data":{"isDirectRight":false,"Left":false,"blockMove":false,"fallSpeed":100,"LeftRelease":false,"LClickRelease":false,"DownRelease":false,"Right":false,"SitRelease":false,"camLeftZ":0.08650045,"camLeftY":-4.0163286E-9,"camLeftX":-0.18032658,"speed":1.0,"LClick":false,"camRotationW":-0.22177358,"camRotationX":-2.1658896E-4,"JumpRelease":false,"startLocation":{"x":-67.11953,"y":8.058952,"z":-55.18904},"camRotationY":0.9750977,"camRotationZ":-9.522566E-4**,**"levelId":"Gilkph036QbP","isRightDirect":false,"isSitRight":false,"Down":false,"camDirectionZ":-0.2704894,"RightRelease":false,"isDirectLeft":false,"camDirectionX":-0.12975043,"camDirectionY":-5.859462E-4,"CtrlRelease":false,"isSit":false,"isSitLeft":false,"Ctrl":false,"Jump":false,"isAnimRun":false,"isLeftDirect":false,"command":1,"rotateAnimation":"direct","isSitRun":false,"runAnimation":"run","gravity":60,"UpRelease":false,"Up":false,"Sit":false,"isStand":false},"user_id":"18","scenario":"send_keys","auth_token":"c0facde0aa585dc4b7e0a6d820bb3df41499141302"}2"}

Where is the mistake?

Comment: It looks OK, you're handling the received datagram length correctly, but the initialization of `byte[] data = new byte[receivePacket.getLength()];` is a complete waste of time and space when you're reassigning `data` in he very next line.

Comment: The mistake is elsewhere.

Comment: You have not shown how you actually KNOW the packet is corrupted, or that you have pinned down where the corruption occurs.  There's clearly a lot more code involved (what is `JInMessages`?), and we cannot possibly guess at a cause.  You must step through the code in the debugger and figure out exactly WHERE the corruption occurs.  If after that you still don't understand what is happening, then post a question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Than'ks i fix this but have same errors

Comment: Manually compare the length of the send and received packet. And compare the received packet length and the string length. It looks like an old buffer is reused and the '2"}' are remains from a an old buffer.

Comment: old variable buffer? thank's i check JInMessages and buffer[]

Comment: while(JUDPRecivier.isRunning){
                receiveData           = new byte[JConfig.socket_buffer_size];
                
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket ( receiveData, receiveData.length );
                serverSocket.receive ( receivePacket );
                
                executor.execute(
                    new JUDPRecivierHandler(serverSocket,receivePacket)
                );
                
                receiveData = null;
            }

Answer (score 0):

fixed
while(JUDPRecivier.isRunning){
                receiveData           = new byte[JConfig.socket_buffer_size];

```
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket ( receiveData, receiveData.length );
            serverSocket.receive ( receivePacket );

            executor.execute(
                new JUDPRecivierHandler(serverSocket,receivePacket)
            );

            receiveData = null;
        }
```